# Проблемы с ботом на пайтон

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, бот

Не работает бот на пайтон, а точнее не выводит второе значение из второго хендлера.

```
from aiogram import Dispatcher, executor, types, Bot
from key import TOKEN_API

bot = Bot(token = TOKEN_API)
dp = Dispatcher(bot = bot)

@dp.message_handler(content_types = "text")
async def oneword_process(msg: types.Message) -> None:
    if len(msg.text.split()) == 1:
        await msg.answer("One word")

@dp.message_handler(content_types = "text")
async def lotsofwords_process(msg: types.Message) -> None:
    if len(msg.text.split()) >= 2:
        await msg.answer("Lots of words")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dispatcher = dp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dp is not defined. Нужен полный код с импортами.

```
# -*- coding: cp1251 -*-

from aiogram import Dispatcher, executor, types, Bot

key = '5869438042:AAHxDpbG1ou13tsai-agJ3BuwOD1KwEc'

bot = Bot(token = key)
dp = Dispatcher(bot = bot)


@dp.message_handler(content_types = 'text')
async def get_text_messages(msg: types.Message):
   if msg.text.lower() == 'привет':
       await msg.answer('Привет!')

   elif msg.text.lower() == 'пока':
       await msg.answer('Пока!')

   else:
        await msg.answer('Я не понимаю')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dispatcher = dp)
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Изменил код на полный

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы if был и в первом и во втором хендлере, как сделать чтобы второй работал?

Comment: Забавно, что в соседнем ответе вы советуете убрать токен, а тут сами свой токен в ответ пишите.